# Convert values between two “contact form 7” dates into javascript/jquery and output range of these dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html, date

**UPDATE:**
Got it working although it doesn't look very clean... If anyone could make it cleaner then You're welcome

```
<div class="column one-fourth" id="date-start">[date* date-start date-format:dd/mm/yy min:today+1days placeholder "Date start"] </div> 
<div class="column one-fourth" id="date-end">[date* date-end placeholder "Date end"] </div>

<p>Start date: <span id="kp1">date</span> <br>
End date: <span id="kp2">date</span> <br>
Number of days: <span id="days">days</span> </p>


<!-- Calculating & stuff -->

<script>
         var date1, date2;
         date1 = document.getElementById("date-start").addEventListener("change", function() {
    input1 = this.value;
    // Value which is needed for a calculation
    var dateEntered1 = new Date(input1);
    dat1 = Math.abs(dateEntered1.getTime());
    document.getElementById("kp1").innerHTML = input1;
});
         date2 = document.getElementById("date-end").addEventListener("change", function() {
    input2 = this.value;
    // Value which is needed for a calculation
    var dateEntered2 = new Date(input2);
    dat2 = Math.abs(dateEntered2.getTime());
    document.getElementById("kp2").innerHTML = input2;

    // Calculating difference between dates
     var timeDiff = (dat2 - dat1) + 1;
     var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
     console.log(diffDays);
    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = diffDays;
});</script>
```

**OLD:**

I'm using contact form 7 regular HTML5 date shortcodes (not datepicker plugin). One for start date. Another one for end date. Firstly I need to somehow get these values. Then I need to output a number which is calculated between these two values.

E.g if I choose 21.10.2018 for start date. And 23.10.2018 for end date then I need to output result as "Number of days: **3**".

Problem is that I don't know how to get that value number between two dates.

I found something from here but I know it's missing some important parts.

Anyway, Contact form 7:

```
<div class="column one-fourth" id="date-start">[date* date-start date-format:dd/mm/yy min:today+1days placeholder "Date start"] </div> 
<div class="column one-fourth" id="date-end">[date* date-end placeholder "Date end"] </div>

<script>
         var date1, date2;
         date1 = document.getElementById("date-start");
         document.write(""+date1);
         date2 = document.getElementById("date-end");
         document.write("<br>"+date2);
         // get total seconds between two dates
         var res = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 1000;
         var days = Math.floor(res / 86400);
         document.write("<br>Number of days: "+days);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm too lazy for these things.. I would use moment.js. This Lib makes all these kind of calculations and much more

Comment: o.k, thanks for guidance :)

Comment: The main problem is that you also have a German ( ? ) date format. JavaScript only understands american format. With the mentioned library you can handle all this .. Of course you can program it all if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clean, but it works.

```
<div class="column one-fourth">[date* date-start id:date-start date-format:dd/mm/yy min:today+1days placeholder "Date start"] </div> 
<div class="column one-fourth">[date* date-end id:date-end placeholder "Date end"] </div>

<p>Start date: <span id="kp1">date</span> <br>
End date: <span id="kp2">date</span> <br>
Number of days: <span id="days">days</span> </p>


<!-- Calculating & stuff -->

<script>
         var date1, date2;
         date1 = document.getElementById("date-start").addEventListener("change", function() {
    input1 = this.value;
    // Value which is needed for a calculation
    var dateEntered1 = new Date(input1);
    dat1 = Math.abs(dateEntered1.getTime());
    document.getElementById("kp1").innerHTML = input1;
});
         date2 = document.getElementById("date-end").addEventListener("change", function() {
    input2 = this.value;
    // Value which is needed for a calculation
    var dateEntered2 = new Date(input2);
    dat2 = Math.abs(dateEntered2.getTime());
    document.getElementById("kp2").innerHTML = input2;

    // Calculating difference between dates
     var timeDiff = (dat2 - dat1) + 1;
     var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
     console.log(diffDays);
    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = diffDays;
});</script>
```